# need wcf and wpf load testing tool

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing

I need to find out the performance of my application.This application works as follows-

It's a WPF windows application, which requires some data to be filled by user
On clicking Submit button, it calls WCF web services
These services save these values in DB
Which tool would be the best for this scenario?

Comment: This appears to be a reproduction or close relative of this thread on SQAForums: http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/performance-load-testing/155276-performance-testing-wpf-desktop-application.html

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be having several thousands of geo-distributed real users having different Internet connection speed and using your WPF application normally. If you are not able to arrange this - I would suggest mimicking these several thousands users on protocol level. You mentioned WCF web services - go and find a web service load testing tool. For example good ones are:

- [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) - designed for web services testing. Has some load testing capabilities. See [Creating and Running LoadTests](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html) to get started.
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org) - multiprotocol load testing tool, supports web services as well. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide.

In fact any tool which is capable of sending a HTTP request will fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of usual load testing tools? for example Apache Jmeter (free) or HP LoadRunner (community license for 50 free users).

Just record communication between your WPF application and WCF ( I belive it communicate via HTTP) and add needed parameters.

Comment: "I belive it communicate via HTTP.."  I have no such assumptions.  WPF applications can speak to any host using any supported protocol...odbc...DCOM..winsock...OleDB...CORBA..native DB..custom protocol.